# nc: run command upon connection

Tags: nc

When doing [CTFs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capture_the_flag#Computer_security), I often run `nc -lnvp $PORT` and do something else while waiting for a connection. I want to be alerted when said connection is established and I get a shell. Since `nc` is not terminated upon connection, I can't use `nc -lnvp $PORT; notify-send "message"`.

Is there a way to run a command (e.g. `notify-send`) when a connection is established with `nc`?

Comment: You could redirect stderr to a file and monitor that file by a second process. When "Connection.*accepted" appears in the file, perform an action. I tried to use Bash's `>(...)` mechanism to avoid creating a file, but I probably misunderstand it and failed.

Comment: @berndbausch I tried `nc -lvp 1337 2> test` with `echo test | entr notify-send 'test'` but that didn't work. Same problem as the one in the question: it's only triggered *after* `nc` has closed the connection.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the word "Connection" appears in the standard error of nc. You could redirect stderr to a named pipe and grep that pipe:

```
mkfifo nc-stderr
nc -lnvp $PORT 2>nc-stderr
```

At a different command line prompt:

```
grep -q 'Connection.*accepted' nc-stderr && notify-send "a connection was accepted"
```